# Making a form display only for a certain value in a SelectField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

i'm a beginner in working with flask.Trying to make a simple cash register app , and i need to make a form display on the page only for a certain value from a SelectField form. Im using wtforms and python !Thanks

#AlexisG   I didn't actually tried anything , i just looked around the net for a solution.
#prabh  i will put below part of the code to explain better

> Blockquote

```
                {{ form.tip.label }}
                {{ form.tip }}
                
                                            
                {{ form.modplata.label }}
                {{ form.modplata }}

                {{ form.suma.label }}
                {{ form.suma(size=7) }}
                {% if form.suma.errors %}                                                      
                    <span style="color:red">{{ form.suma.errors[1] }}</span>
                {% endif %}

                {{ form.nume.label }}
                {{ form.nume(size=20) }}

                
                {{ form.submit }}
```

form.tip is a SelectField form with 4 choices , i'm trying to make another SelectField form to display in html without refreshing the page for a certain choice in form.tip ! Hope i was clear . Thank you!

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Can you show us chat you have tried ?

Comment: what issue are you facing?